# Downgrade itunes in high sierra

Tags: itunes, mac, jailbreak, downgrade, sip

So I need to downgrade itunes to 12.0.1 for a jailbreak (6.1.6 on ipod 4g). Currently, you can't just delete itunes. What would I have to do?

My idea is:

- Disable SIP (boot into recovery mode and disable)
- Delete the Itunes Application
- Install the 12.0.1 Itunes

Is it that simple? Anything else I need to remove? I'm trying to get either redsn0w or p0sixspawn to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are reading this, this may not be how to downgrade itunes, but this is how I used a different version.

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Obtain a .iso version of windows, and Boot it in VirtualBox
3. download itunes version needed from [here](https://filehippo.com/download_itunes/64/) within VirtualBox
4. Do what you need

Comment: You could also use the free trial version of Parallels which would be easier.